# How to I return the key number I just added to an array in PHP by using [ ]?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a while loop, and in the loop I am appending keys to an array using

```
$my_array[] = $array_element;
```

Code snippet:

```
<?php
$raw_string = 'David,Frank,Hal9000,Victor,Jack,Charles'
$put_into_array = explode(',', $raw_string);
$my_array = array();
foreach($put_into_array AS $array_element){
    if($array_element != 'Hal9000'){
        $living_crew[] = $array_element;
        if(  //The array key is the 2nd key//  ){
             $lost_in_space_by = $tried_to_retrieve;
             ////DO SOMETHING HERE////
        }
        if(  //The array key is the 1st key//  ){
             $tried_to_retrieve = //this key//;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

I am looking for a way to get the value I just added with the [] infront of $my_array. I know this particular example can be solved in other ways, but the point is to learn the function, not to solve this one example in other ways. This is expected to behave similar to the now-depricated mysql_insert_id() function.

thanks!

Comment: count($living_crew) - 1

Comment: wait are you looking for the key or value?

Comment: you can also use `end($living_crey); return key($living_crew);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$idx = array_push($living_crew, $xxx) - 1
```

instead of

```
$living_crew[] = $xxx;
```

It returns the length of array. 
see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: It's zero based indexing so you need to subtract 1 to fix the index